# gerund or infinitive? (make or making)

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure

In the following sentence, why has it used in a -ing having form? In general, when should we use gerund or infinitive after preposition of "to"?

> Like Hercules, he devotes his life to **making** the world a safer place.

Comment: Hold on! The "to" that introduces infinitival clauses is a subordinator, but the "to" that takes gerund-participials as complement is a preposition. Your example belongs in the latter category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in this case, "to" is used as a part of a phrasal verb or verb + preposition combination. One popular example of this usage is below:

> I look forward to meeting your parents tonight

check this below link for other cases where you should use "verb+ing" after "to"

[link](http://www.englishteachermelanie.com/grammar-can-a-gerund-be-used-after-to/)

Answer (score 1):

Here, *making the world a safer place* is a gerund phrase, and the *to* is purely as a preposition, not as an indicator of infinitive. Just like you might say to your spouse "I devote my life **to you**". Hercules, and the subject of this sentence, devote their life to the *act* or *idea*, or *pursuit*, of making the world a safer place.